# Buscar un elemento de tipo string en una lista de C#

Tags: c#, lista, vscode

Tengo que hacer una lista en C# y una de las opciones que debe tener la lista es poder buscar un elemento  y mostrarlo en un cuadro de texto, en caso de que no exista, indicar mediante mensaje que dicho elemento no existe.

Adjunto imagen de todo el mandato junto a el código que he desarrollado.
[![imagen de todo lo pedido][1]][1]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace lista_de_series
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    List<string> listanombres = new List<string>();
    private object txt_list_nombres;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string nombre;

        nombre = txt_nombres.Text;
        listanombres.Add(nombre);

        list_nombres.DataSource = null;
        list_nombres.DataSource = listanombres;

    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var indice = listanombres.IndexOf(txt_nombreacambiar.Text);
        listanombres.RemoveAt(indice);
        listanombres.Insert(indice,txt_nombres.Text);

        list_nombres.DataSource = null;
        list_nombres.DataSource = listanombres;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

 


    private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void txt_nombreacambiar_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    
    private void list_nombres_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var indice = listanombres.IndexOf(txt_nombreacambiar.Text);
        
        listanombres.Insert(indice, txt_nombres.Text);

        list_nombres.DataSource = null;
        list_nombres.DataSource = listanombres;





    }

    private void btn_buscar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (list_nombres.Contains(txt_nombres.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("El elemento existe", "sistema administrativo", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        }
     
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("El elemento no existe", "sistema administrativo", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        }
   }
}
}
```

como pueden ver he utilizado una estructura if else para esa parte del código pero me da error y no tengo la mas mínima idea de que puedo hacer.

PD: tuve que borrar parte del codigo para poder subirlo pero ahí les dejo lo mas importante

Comment: Primero: aclara que es list_nombres, por casualidad es un bindingSource? Segundo: por lo que veo en tu codigo no te hace falta poner list_nombres.DataSource = null; asi que esa sentencia puedes quitarla.Tercero: muestra que error te da. Como consejo general te digo que uses nombres descriptivos, en vez de poner button1 es mejor que pongas por ejemplo btnAnnadirNombre, ya que eso es lo que hace ese boton y es mas facil para uno entender tu codigo y para ti tambien, ya que cuando pasen 3 meses ni tu te vas a acordar de lo que hace button1, por eso la importancia de usar nombres descriptivos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si deseas saber si un elemento de la lista que contenga determinado texto, puedes iterar sobre la lista y buscar el texto definido, cuando se encuentre usas el indice para eliminar el elemento:

```
Boolean existe = false;

for (int i = 0; i < listanombres.Count; i++) 
 {
    //Busca si texto se encuentra en ArrayList.
    if(listanombres[i].Contains(txt_nombres.Text))
    {         
      existe = true;
    } 
}

    if (existe)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("El elemento existe", "sistema administrativo", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
    }     
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("El elemento no existe", "sistema administrativo", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
    }
```

Comment: Esta respuesta no tiene relación con la pregunta. Y si se tratara en realidad de una eliminación, el código propuesto eliminará más de un elemento.

Comment: Gracias Pablo, el código fue editado y se agrega validación para mostrar mensaje en caso de encontrar el elemento en el ArrayList, saludos.

Comment: @Jorgesys, no entiendo porque remueves el elemento si el usuario lo único que quiere es saber si existe, el código de eliminación sobra

Comment: @Japv Así es, se actualizo la respuesta.

Comment: muchas gracias por su ayuda, fue muy util y para la proxima sabre como resolverlo